# React/Redux Github pages does not work with browserHistory

Tags: redux, react-router, github-pages, browser-history

I have an react/redux app on Github pages. I used `browserHistory` from `react-router`, and the page won't show up with no error messages.

When change from `browserHistory` to `hashHistory`, then everything works just fine.

Any reason why this is happening? Could I use `browserHistory` and still work?

Thanks
Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

In order to use browserHistory you will need a real app server to handle the request and redirect all nont-root level requests back to /. Since GitHub pages is nothing more than a static files host, you can't use browserHistory on it.

Reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory